# Prove that $B$ is a basis of $R_n$ iff $\mathbf A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in \mathbf M_{n\times n}(R)$ and let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis of $R_n$.
>   Prove that $B = \{\mathbf Av_1,...,\mathbf Av_n\}$ is a basis of $R_n$ if and only if $A$ is invertible.

My idea is that $B$ is basis so $B$ is linearly independent then $\text{rank}(B) = n$, but it can not prove $A$ is invertible. Am I on the right track? Can someone give a hint where should I start?

Related: Example 3.5C, P178, *Intro to Lin Alg*, 4th Ed, G Strang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another approach. Let
$$B := \begin{bmatrix} Av_1 & \dots & Av_n \end{bmatrix}, \quad V := \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \dots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$$
be matrices with columns $Av_k$ and $v_k$, respectively. Then
$$B = AV.$$
Since the columns of a square matrix $V$ are linearly independent, it is invertible, which means that
$$A = BV^{-1}.$$
In other words, $A$ is invertible if and only if $B$ is such, which proves your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also ${\rm rank}(A)=\dim ({\rm im\,}A)=n$, as $B=\{Av_1,..,Av_n\}$ spans the whole image (column space) of $A$.

You may also want to apply the dimension theorem (or *rank+nullity theorem*):
$$\dim({\rm im\,}A)+\dim(\ker A)=n$$
If $A$ is a linear map from an $n$ dimensional vector space (a matrix $A$ can be identified with the linear map $v\mapsto Av$).

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $\mathbf A$ is a matrix whose columns are coordinates of $\mathbf Av_i$ with respect to the basis $A$.

Vectors in $A$ can be expressed as linear combinations of vectors in $B$ because $B$ is a basis. The coefficients will form a matrix $\mathbf B$ whose columns are coordinates of $v_i$ with respect to the basis $B$. You can then verify that $\mathbf A\mathbf B$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is a basis, considering $A$ as a linear map on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ certainly is surjective, since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can find scalars $\lambda_i$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i Av_i = A \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i\bigg) = x$$

Furthermore, $A$ is one-to-one, since $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iAv_i = 0$ implies $\lambda_i = 0$ by linear independence, and so $\ker A = \{0\}$.  Hence, $A$ is invertible.

For the converse, it suffices to show that $B$ is linearly independent.  So suppose

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i Av_i =A \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i\bigg)0$$

Since $\ker A = \{0\}$,.......Finish the argument.